# Why does Optional Binding evaluate to type Bool?

Tags: swift

Why is this variable i not substituted for Bool but optional binding is?
Swift claims this in the guide..

> Swift’s type safety prevents non-Boolean values from being substituted
>   for Bool. The following example reports a compile-time error:

```
let i = 1
if i {
    // this example will not compile, and will report an error
}
```

Yet this compiles

```
var foo: String?

if let bar = foo {
    print("Non nil")
}
```

Comment: Why should the first example compile in the first place?

Comment: Not quite sure why I'm getting downvotes.. my question is within SO guidelines and is valid as I'm learning Swift. Tisk tisk you question Nazis.

Comment: It is an example from the guide. If swift converted the value of an expression to type Bool then the first example would compile. That is why I had confusion regarding the second example.

Comment: There are no bools in the second example `if let` pattern is very different from `if`. `if` checks a boolean condition while `if let` unwraps an optional to a new variable if non-nil. No boolean appears there.

Comment: Thank you, Ike10 cleared that up for me. I'm still a Swift noob as I interpreted if let as if (let foo = bar) instead of an entirely different conditional statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An optional is essentially an enum with two possible values either a designated value, in your example a string, or `nil`. An `if let` binding is not being substituted for a `Bool` in your example. Instead, it is checking if the variable `foo` is `nil` and if it is not `nil` then it sets `bar` equal to `foo` and performs the code inside the block. An `if let` binding is thus essentially a shortcut for

```
var foo: String?
if foo != nil {
   //Set bar equal to the unwrapped value of foo
   let bar = foo!
   //Do whatever
}
```

The efficiency of this is best shown in a case where you would want to check if something is `nil` and check some characteristic of the value if it is not nil. Say you wanted to also check that `foo` has more than 5 characters and if it does then do something. Since `foo` could be `nil` you would have to check for it specifically to ensure it is not. An `if let` binding will let you do this:

```
if let bar = foo where bar.characters.count > 5 {
    print(bar)
}
```

rather than this:

```
 if foo != nil && foo?.characters.count > 5 {
   let bar = foo!
   print(bar)
 }
```

It basically makes very readable, and thus more maintainable code. Also, it prevents you from having to unwrap the optional manually (the `!` operator at the end of `foo`).

Comment: Thank you. The main confusion I had was that the result of setting the constant to the value of the unwrapped optional acts as if the expression was evaluated to true and executes the block of code. Although expressions do not evaluate to Bool in Swift. Maybe I'm just retarded but regarding the statement I quoted from the documentation it just seemed off.